# Open XML SDK en Visual Basic 6

Tags: vb6

¿Es compatible esta librería con Visual Basic 6? ¿Como podría añadir la referencia a dicha librería?

Comment: ¿Has buscado en google?

Comment: Lo dudo mucho la verdad. Ese SDK es exclusivo para .net si no me equivoco.

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias.